# git-svn password change

Tags: git, passwords, git-svn

I'm using TortoiseGit on Windows XP.

My team all use a central svn server as our central "canonical" code repository. It's all run on a windows network.

I work locally with git, then use git-svn dcommit to commit regularly to the svn server.

Our network enforces a regular password change - which changes my password for the svn server as well. Now I can't dcommit any more, as Tortoise is attempting to use my old password - I've googled, and I've hunted thru menus and docs - but I can't figure out where to change the password that Git uses to connect to SVN. Anyone help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`git-svn` uses Subversion’s perl modules which in turn uses “normal” Subversion authentication. That means that your authentication data is stored somewhere in `$HOME/.subversion`, e.g. in one of the files in `$HOME/.subversion/svn.simple/` when you are using a simple username-password combination to authenticate.

Comment: Thanks Bombe - exactly what I needed. I was a bit disturbed to see the password stored in plain text though!

For anyone else reading this and using the same combo of Windows XP and TortoiseGit, it's in:

C:\Documents and Settings\WINDOWSUSERNAME\.subversion\auth\svn.simple

Comment: This question contains steps to prevent SVN from storing your password https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43285/disable-svn-plaintext-password-storage-for-all-users

Answer (score 8):

On a Windows box it will be something like

C:\Users\uttamk\.subversion\auth\svn.simple

Just delete all the files in the folder. The password will be reset

Answer (score 4):

On Windows 7 and onwards, the place to look is

```
%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth
```

which usually resolves to

```
C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth
```